# How to save generated PDF with JasperReports into server Yii

Tags: php, yii, jasper-reports

I need to save my generated PDF file into my server. I am using JasperReports.

Code sample for PDF generation:

```
$this->widget('ext.Yiijasperserver.Yiijasperserver', array(
    'path' => '/reports/Crescent/call_list_report',
    'format' => 'pdf',
    'out' => 'I',
    'file' => 'call_list_report',
    'parameter' => array(
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'from_date' => $from_date,
        'to_date' => $to_date,
        'status_id' => $status_id
    )
));
```

Comment: What is your actual query?

Comment: @Bipin: [How to upload a file using a model](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/how-to-upload-a-file-using-a-model/)

Comment: @Bikash The query is in the jasper report here we just pass the parameter for query.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the answer. Added below code in  `Yiijasperserver.php` file in extension folder yii

```
public function run()
    {
        $client = new Jasper\JasperClient('localhost',
                   8080,
                  'jasperadmin', 
                  'jaspSyo@321*',
                  '/jasperserver');


    $report = $client->runReport($this->path, $this->format,$this->page,$this->parameter);

    header('Content-type: '.$this->mimetype[$this->format]);
            if($this->out=="I")
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$this->file.'.'.$this->format.'"');
    if($this->out=="D")
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$this->file.'.'.$this->format.'"');


$file1 = 'C:\HostingSpaces\new.pdf';//New code added
file_put_contents($file1, $report);//New code added
echo $report;

}
```